# Narrow a union type based on properties already set within an object

Tags: typescript, intellisense

```
interface MockHTMLDivElement {
  divPropA: string,
  divPropB: string,
}

interface MockHTMLButtonElement {
  buttonPropA: string,
  buttonPropB: string,
}

type MockElement =
  | MockHTMLDivElement
  | MockHTMLButtonElement

const el: MockElement = {
  buttonPropA: 'foo', // implies that this is a MockHTMLButtonElement
  d // intellisense shows divPropA, divPropB here, even though buttonPropA is already 
    // present and implies this is a MockHTMLButtonElement and not a MockHTMLDivElement
}
```

Intellisense will still show `divPropA` and `divPropB` as possible properties for this object even though the object already has a `buttonPropA` property, which would imply that it's a `MockHTMLButtonElement`.

Is there a way to type this better so that Intellisense knows this is either a `MockHTMLButtonElement` or a `MockHTMLDivElement` and only show properties for one type or the other rather than showing properties from both types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `buttonPropA` property is not a discriminant for the union, because the type of this property is not prohibited by the `MockHTMLDivElement` type, so `{buttonPropA: 'foo', divPropA: 'bar', divPropB: 'baz'}` is allowed as a value of type `MockHTMLDivElement`.

If you use a discriminated union instead, then only the properties from the consistent branch will be suggested. In the example below, `kind` is the discriminant.

```
interface MockHTMLDivElement {
  kind: 'div',
  divPropA: string,
  divPropB: string,
}

interface MockHTMLButtonElement {
  kind: 'button',
  buttonPropA: string,
  buttonPropB: string,
}

type MockElement = MockHTMLDivElement | MockHTMLButtonElement

const el: MockElement = {
  kind: 'button',
  buttonPropA: 'foo',
  b, // suggestions include 'buttonPropB'
  d, // no suggestions
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIHsEGsASAVVAGQBFgA3AUQBsIBbCcZAbwChlktQATALmQHIu5fgBo2yIWQAKUdAAcAgnwDOYKKADmY9pJnyAQirWaxAXxYtQkWIhQZs+IvoCuYMOhDU6DMM3GcQXgEAI1d3EFFxULcPPUUjdRAtKLDY2TlDZFVE5PMWMABPOTtMLC96RgBeNFLHEnJyn2QAHxqHAkIXGM8aCrALBA9VZAgqPnsy3qbq1nYAoP5o8Mj2JbT5JQEYdHQV5GCRZAB6I6znDQ0IVWAh5FAEKmcuFEXUkDj9fnEuQ5PkEHQZwuVzANxAyhY5iAA)